# Replacing item in bound array renders it briefly without it

Tags: jquery, html, css, ember.js

I've got a playlist with artwork images. When I click on one the old current track is taking their place. Therefore I replace the item in the array.

When Ember re-renders the items for a very brief moment the replaced element disappears. This leads to an ugly effect where everything is re-positioned.

**You can see the effect here**

- Go to http://ali.dj/blog
- Click on one of the three playlist-images

This is my simplified **controller**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  playlist: null,
  currentTrack: null;
  actions: {
    replaceItem: function(){
      playlist.replace(index, 1, [self.get("currentTrack")])
    } 
  }
}
```

This is the **template**:

```
{{#each song in playlist}}
  <div class="song" {{action "changeTrack" song}}>
    <img {{bind-attr src=song.artwork_url}} />
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

EDIT: I created a JSFiddle but could **NOT** reproduce my problem with plain jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/bhn8bko1/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the selected playlist is moving over and then fading to transparent before appearing as the current playlist. Because it fades out you still see the old playlist through it, and then quickly see it switch. If you had the new playlist scale back down to the size it started at instead of fading out to transparent, you wouldn't see the jump. It would just reduce in size whilst staying opaque, and then make the switch behind the scenes.

The old playlist would still 'jump-appear' on the right, but that could possibly be softened with a fade in.

Comment: After fading out it simply appears again at its old position. Then the replace  happens. I made a JSFiddle and couldn't reproduce the problem there http://jsfiddle.net/bhn8bko1/2/ I already tried a fadein and it still looks bad.